# How to install 'savon' gems on Windows machine?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, savon

How to install 'savon' gems in Windows machine, though I've download the gem and save into the ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems folder. But it still show me the error in command prompt that:

> :gem_original_require no such file to load --savon

Comment: Run `gem install savon` on the command promt.

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference between the Linux or Windows way to install a gem. from the command line run

```
gem install savon
```

and off you go.